# Jqgrid upload image not passing data object to database

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

This is a last attempt for me to get some insight on this issue before I scratch JqGrid all together. I have a col in my colModel to upload an Image. I am using ajaxfileupload. Although there are several of the same examples out there they seem to work for others but mine is not. When I select an Image from the enctype: "multipart/form-data" for some reason it is not putting anything in the record for the object. I have a few breakpoints and when I view the data everything is visible but the product Image. So all fields are there and ProductImage is null. It is like JqGrid is not holding the object and passing it. Since it is null, nothing gets uploaded either. Maybe I am missing something but I have looked through my code over and over again and it appears to be just like what I have read in examples that supposedly work.

Any help with would be fantastic as I am ready to scratch this and use something else.

Below is my code for the process. sections only. if you need to see other code let me know.

JqGrid:

```
                {
                name: "ProductImage",
                index: "ProductImage",
                mtype: "Post",
                editable: true,
                editrules: { required: true },
                edittype: "file",
                search: true,
                resizable: false,
                width: 210,
                align: "left",
                editoptions: {
                    enctype: "multipart/form-data"
                }
            },
```

.....

```
        {
            // edit option
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/Admin/EditProducts",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            afterSubmit: uploadImage,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }

        },
```

....

```
function uploadImage(response, postdata) {
    //debugger;
    //var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
    //if (json) return [json.success, json.message, json.id];
    //return [false, "Failed to get result from server.", null];
    var data = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);

    if (data.success == true) {
        if ($("#ProductImage").val() != "") {
            ajaxFileUpload(data.id);
        }
    }

    return [data.success, data.message, data.id];
}

function ajaxFileUpload(id) {

    $.ajaxFileUpload(
        {
            url: "/Admin/UploadImage",
            secureuri: false,
            fileElementId: "ProductImage",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (data, status) {

                if (typeof (data.isUploaded) != "undefined") {
                    if (data.isUploaded == true) {
                        return;
                    } else {
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return alert("Failed to upload image!");
                }
            },
            error: function (data, status, e) {
                return alert("Failed to upload image!");
            }
        }
    )

    return false;
}
```

Controller:

```
   public string EditProducts(Product product)
    {
        string msg;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (StoreEntities db = new StoreEntities())
                {
                    db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    msg = "Saved Successfully";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Did not save! ";
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        //catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
            foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                               validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

....

```
    #region Upload Images

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase ProductImage)
    {
        string directory = "~/Images/";

        if (ProductImage != null && ProductImage.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(ProductImage.FileName);
            ProductImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(directory, fileName)));
            //ProductImage.SaveAs(Path.Combine(directory, fileName));
        }

        return Json(new { isUploaded = true, message = "Uploaded Successfully" }, "text/html");
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Before to try to solve the problem, we would like to know
The version of jqGrid used? - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <=4.7
The version of jQuery used
The version of ajaxFileUpload plugin used

Comment: JqGrid is 4.4.4 downloaded through NuGet packages and seems to be the latest version. Which may pose an issue because I am using Jquery 3.3.1 and JqueryUI1.2.I just saw that JqGrid is compatible with 1.9.1 and 1.10.0 UI. Why there is not a newer version I do not know. Git hub does with 5.3.0 but appears to be PHP based. And the Ajax file Upload appears not to show a version. I have downloaded the AjaxControlkit from NuGet ver 18.1.0 But I do not see any related files from the install in my project.

Comment: I have gotten the file to upload but I am still not able to save the file name in the database that it uploads. So when I upload an image I would like the record to save the filename in the column ProductImage